# OpenVPN - ERROR: Cannot open TUN/TAP dev /dev/net/tun: No such file or directory (errno=2)

Tags: linux, debian, openvpn

There are lots of questions pertaining this error, and there is a suggested manual fix which works well, but there's no permanent solution. How can i permanently solve this? Im having this issue on a debian wheezy server, using OpenVPN client to connect to an OpenVPN server.

The suggested fix is the one below. Seems like, /dev/net is not automatically created and of course disappears on each reboot.

```
mkdir -p /dev/net
mknod /dev/net/tun c 10 200
chmod 600 /dev/net/tun
```

Comment: it's work like a charm on synology nas, i was try to use zerotier and was unable until i see this answer !!!

Answer (score 8):

It happens in Arch/Manjaro as well.

I managed to figure out the problem, apparently a kernel upgrade is simply moving the modules directory, so trying to reach the modules from their known location is unavailable, the current running kernel is still running but I can't seem to `modprobe` (load) any modules which are not already loaded (such as `tun` required for OpenVPN connections).

So for example, the `/lib/modules/` directory had the following directories before the upgrade (I have multiple kernels, notice the 5.16 series):

```
5.15.32-1-MANJARO  *5.16.14-1-MANJARO*  extramodules-5.15-MANJARO  extramodules-5.16-MANJARO
```

And this is the status after the upgrade:

```
5.15.32-1-MANJARO  *5.16.18-1-MANJARO*  extramodules-5.15-MANJARO  extramodules-5.16-MANJARO
```

Trying to load the `tun` modules shows the following message:

```
modprobe: FATAL: Module tun not found in directory /lib/modules/5.16.14-1-MANJARO
```

Which perfectly makes sense as this directory doesn't exist.
So, what is my proposed solution in this case? A restart.

Answer (score 6):

debian wheezy has been out of support since may 2018 (https://www.debian.org/releases/wheezy/), you should not be using it in 2020 any more for production.

Now, with that out of the way, you could add the commands that temporarily fix your issue adding those commands a bash script that you add to your root crontab with the @reboot nickname (man 5 crontab).

So create a bash script somewhere in your file system with something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

mkdir -p /dev/net
mknod /dev/net/tun c 10 200
chmod 600 /dev/net/tun

/etc/init.d/openvpn restart
```

Save it with 755 permissions and modify the root crontab:

```
# crontab -e
```

with this content at least

```
@reboot /path/to/where/you/saved/the/script
```

And after rebooting it should have started openvpn successfully.

Comment: As an alternative, the code snippet can be be written into `/etc/default/openvpn` file, which is sourced by `/etc/init.d/openvpn` script.

Comment: nice, I do not have a debian wheezy handy to test, but this should be the preferred option if it works

Answer (score 3):

I think that a possible solution is to configure the system to load the `tun` kernel module during startup. In order to do so, list the `tun` module name in `/etc/modules` file:

```
# echo tun >> /etc/modules
```

`udev` is the system component that <s>creates and</s> maintains device nodes in `/dev` folder according to loaded kernel modules and connected hardware devices. I believe that by loading `tun` kernel module at boot time, the system will create the `/dev/net/tun` device node on every startup.

I hope it helps.

---

**EDIT:** I am a bit outdated. After launching a Debian Wheezy image published in [Vagrant Cloud website](https://app.vagrantup.com/deb/boxes/wheezy-amd64), I figured out that `udev` in fact handles permissions, ownerships and symlinks regarding already existing device nodes. Device nodes are actually created by the kernel itself and are exposed to userspace through the `devtmpfs` pseudo-filesystem.

`devtmpfs` filesystem is mounted at initramfs time. The file `/usr/share/initramfs-tools/init`, which gets executed once `grub` extracts initramfs to memory, presents code that mounts a `devtmpfs` filesystem into `/dev`, falling back to a standard `tmpfs` filesystem if unsuccessful.

In addition, to have `devtmpfs` filesystem available, Debian Wheezy kernel is shipped with `CONFIG_DEVTMPFS=y` enabled.

Comment: On Busybox systems I have experienced that `tun.o` or `tun.ko` does exist in the default modules directory. In that case `insmod /path/to/tun.o` will be the way to go?

Comment: Anderson, i tried the suggested solution, but it doesn't work

Comment: @LasseMichaelMølgaard It depends on how the Busybox system is implemented. I am not sure on how device nodes are maintained in such systems. Anyway, `modprobe` and `insmod` are to kernel modules as `apt-get` and `dpkg` are to software packages, so `insmod` may work.

Comment: @Joe Interesting. So I think that the only option is to automate the manual fix at boot time, as [@natxo asenjo's answer](https://serverfault.com/a/1003129/293407).