# ERR OpenVPN is not listening (Raspberry PI using pivpn)

Tags: linux, openvpn, raspbian

I am trying to get my old pi running a VPN server so I can access local resources from outside my local network.

Following the steps below:

`curl -L https://install.pivpn.io | bash`

*Selecting default settings, OpenVPN, DHCP reservation, udp, port 1194, CloudFlare and rebooting*

`pivpn add`

Trying to connect to the server from another device with the generated .ovpn file imported brings no joy.

I have tried uninstalling and reinstalling OpenVPN following the same steps, which to no surprise gave the same outcome.

When rebooting, I get `[OK] started OpenVPN service` then `[FAILED] Failed to start OpenVPN connection to server`

This suggests running the command `systemctl status openvpn@server.service`

Doing this gives the following output:

```
● openvpn@server.service - OpenVPN connection to server
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/openvpn@.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: activating (auto-restart) (Result: exit-code) since Wed 2022-03-30 12:35:52 BST; 231ms ago
       Docs: man:openvpn(8)
             https://community.openvpn.net/openvpn/wiki/Openvpn24ManPage
             https://community.openvpn.net/openvpn/wiki/HOWTO
    Process: 744 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/openvpn --daemon ovpn-server --status /run/openvpn/server.status 10 --cd /etc/openvpn --config /etc/openvpn/server.conf --writepid /run/openvpn/server.pid (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
   Main PID: 744 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
        CPU: 274ms
```

`pivpn -d` gives the following output:

```
::: Generating Debug Output
::::            PiVPN debug              ::::
=============================================
::::            Latest commit            ::::
Branch: master
Commit: f80b0a7962d91862132c0a4abd65c1e67bd37bd7
Author: 4s3ti
Date: Fri Dec 3 21:41:13 2021 +0100
Summary: Update Changelog
=============================================
::::        Installation settings        ::::
PLAT=Raspbian
OSCN=bullseye
USING_UFW=0
IPv4dev=wlan0
dhcpReserv=1
IPv4addr=192.168.1.212/24
IPv4gw=192.168.1.254
install_user=pi
install_home=/home/pi
VPN=openvpn
pivpnPROTO=udp
pivpnPORT=1194
pivpnDNS1=1.1.1.1
pivpnDNS2=1.0.0.1
pivpnSEARCHDOMAIN=
pivpnHOST=REDACTED
TWO_POINT_FOUR=1
pivpnENCRYPT=256
USE_PREDEFINED_DH_PARAM=
INPUT_CHAIN_EDITED=0
FORWARD_CHAIN_EDITED=0
pivpnDEV=tun0
pivpnNET=10.8.0.0
subnetClass=24
ALLOWED_IPS=""
UNATTUPG=1
INSTALLED_PACKAGES=(openvpn)
HELP_SHOWN=1
=============================================
::::  Server configuration shown below   ::::
dev tun
proto udp
port 1194
ca /etc/openvpn/easy-rsa/pki/ca.crt
cert /etc/openvpn/easy-rsa/pki/issued/raspberrypi_9b23f305-6583-48ad-b87a-1815a883620c.crt
key /etc/openvpn/easy-rsa/pki/private/raspberrypi_9b23f305-6583-48ad-b87a-1815a883620c.key
dh none
ecdh-curve prime256v1
topology subnet
server 10.8.0.0 255.255.255.0
# Set your primary domain name server address for clients
push "dhcp-option DNS 1.1.1.1"
push "dhcp-option DNS 1.0.0.1"
# Prevent DNS leaks on Windows
push "block-outside-dns"
# Override the Client default gateway by using 0.0.0.0/1 and
# 128.0.0.0/1 rather than 0.0.0.0/0. This has the benefit of
# overriding but not wiping out the original default gateway.
push "redirect-gateway def1"
client-to-client
client-config-dir /etc/openvpn/ccd
keepalive 15 120
remote-cert-tls client
tls-version-min 1.2
tls-crypt /etc/openvpn/easy-rsa/pki/ta.key
cipher AES-256-CBC
auth SHA256
user openvpn
group openvpn
persist-key
persist-tun
crl-verify /etc/openvpn/crl.pem
status /var/log/openvpn-status.log 20
status-version 3
syslog
verb 3
#DuplicateCNs allow access control on a less-granular, per user basis.
#Remove # if you will manage access by user instead of device.
#duplicate-cn
# Generated for use by PiVPN.io
=============================================
::::  Client template file shown below   ::::
client
dev tun
proto udp
remote REDACTED 1194
resolv-retry infinite
nobind
remote-cert-tls server
tls-version-min 1.2
verify-x509-name raspberrypi_9b23f305-6583-48ad-b87a-1815a883620c name
cipher AES-256-CBC
auth SHA256
auth-nocache
verb 3
=============================================
::::    Recursive list of files in       ::::
::: /etc/openvpn/easy-rsa/pki shows below :::
/etc/openvpn/easy-rsa/pki/:
ca.crt
crl.pem
Default.txt
ecparams
index.txt
index.txt.attr
index.txt.attr.old
index.txt.old
iphone.ovpn
issued
openssl-easyrsa.cnf
private
renewed
revoked
safessl-easyrsa.cnf
serial
serial.old
ta.key

/etc/openvpn/easy-rsa/pki/ecparams:
prime256v1.pem

/etc/openvpn/easy-rsa/pki/issued:
iphone.crt
raspberrypi_9b23f305-6583-48ad-b87a-1815a883620c.crt

/etc/openvpn/easy-rsa/pki/private:
ca.key
iphone.key
raspberrypi_9b23f305-6583-48ad-b87a-1815a883620c.key

/etc/openvpn/easy-rsa/pki/renewed:
private_by_serial
reqs_by_serial

/etc/openvpn/easy-rsa/pki/renewed/private_by_serial:

/etc/openvpn/easy-rsa/pki/renewed/reqs_by_serial:

/etc/openvpn/easy-rsa/pki/revoked:
private_by_serial
reqs_by_serial

/etc/openvpn/easy-rsa/pki/revoked/private_by_serial:

/etc/openvpn/easy-rsa/pki/revoked/reqs_by_serial:
=============================================
::::            Self check               ::::
:: [OK] IP forwarding is enabled
:: [OK] Iptables MASQUERADE rule set
:: [OK] OpenVPN is running
:: [OK] OpenVPN is enabled (it will automatically start on reboot)
:: [ERR] OpenVPN is not listening, try to restart now? [Y/n] y
Done
[INFO] Run pivpn -d again to see if we detect issues
=============================================
:::: Having trouble connecting? Take a look at the FAQ:
:::: https://docs.pivpn.io/faq
=============================================
::::      Snippet of the server log      ::::
Mar 30 11:56:14 raspberrypi ovpn-server[27301]: Consider setting groups/curves preference with tls-groups instead of forcing a specific curve with ecdh-curve.
Mar 30 11:56:14 raspberrypi ovpn-server[27301]: DEPRECATED OPTION: --cipher set to 'AES-256-CBC' but missing in --data-ciphers (AES-256-GCM:AES-128-GCM). Future OpenVPN version will ignore --cipher for cipher negotiations. Add 'AES-256-CBC' to --data-ciphers or change --cipher 'AES-256-CBC' to --data-ciphers-fallback 'AES-256-CBC' to silence this warning.
Mar 30 11:56:14 raspberrypi ovpn-server[27301]: Options error: --writepid fails with '/run/openvpn/server.pid': No such file or directory (errno=2)
Mar 30 11:56:14 raspberrypi ovpn-server[27301]: Options error: Please correct these errors.
Mar 30 11:56:14 raspberrypi ovpn-server[27301]: Use --help for more information.
Mar 30 11:56:19 raspberrypi ovpn-server[27314]: Consider setting groups/curves preference with tls-groups instead of forcing a specific curve with ecdh-curve.
Mar 30 11:56:19 raspberrypi ovpn-server[27314]: DEPRECATED OPTION: --cipher set to 'AES-256-CBC' but missing in --data-ciphers (AES-256-GCM:AES-128-GCM). Future OpenVPN version will ignore --cipher for cipher negotiations. Add 'AES-256-CBC' to --data-ciphers or change --cipher 'AES-256-CBC' to --data-ciphers-fallback 'AES-256-CBC' to silence this warning.
Mar 30 11:56:19 raspberrypi ovpn-server[27314]: Options error: --writepid fails with '/run/openvpn/server.pid': No such file or directory (errno=2)
Mar 30 11:56:19 raspberrypi ovpn-server[27314]: Options error: Please correct these errors.
Mar 30 11:56:19 raspberrypi ovpn-server[27314]: Use --help for more information.
Mar 30 11:56:30 raspberrypi ovpn-server[27322]: Consider setting groups/curves preference with tls-groups instead of forcing a specific curve with ecdh-curve.
Mar 30 11:56:30 raspberrypi ovpn-server[27322]: DEPRECATED OPTION: --cipher set to 'AES-256-CBC' but missing in --data-ciphers (AES-256-GCM:AES-128-GCM). Future OpenVPN version will ignore --cipher for cipher negotiations. Add 'AES-256-CBC' to --data-ciphers or change --cipher 'AES-256-CBC' to --data-ciphers-fallback 'AES-256-CBC' to silence this warning.
Mar 30 11:56:30 raspberrypi ovpn-server[27322]: Options error: --writepid fails with '/run/openvpn/server.pid': No such file or directory (errno=2)
Mar 30 11:56:30 raspberrypi ovpn-server[27322]: Options error: Please correct these errors.
Mar 30 11:56:30 raspberrypi ovpn-server[27322]: Use --help for more information.
Mar 30 11:56:36 raspberrypi ovpn-server[27334]: Consider setting groups/curves preference with tls-groups instead of forcing a specific curve with ecdh-curve.
Mar 30 11:56:36 raspberrypi ovpn-server[27334]: DEPRECATED OPTION: --cipher set to 'AES-256-CBC' but missing in --data-ciphers (AES-256-GCM:AES-128-GCM). Future OpenVPN version will ignore --cipher for cipher negotiations. Add 'AES-256-CBC' to --data-ciphers or change --cipher 'AES-256-CBC' to --data-ciphers-fallback 'AES-256-CBC' to silence this warning.
Mar 30 11:56:36 raspberrypi ovpn-server[27334]: Options error: --writepid fails with '/run/openvpn/server.pid': No such file or directory (errno=2)
Mar 30 11:56:36 raspberrypi ovpn-server[27334]: Options error: Please correct these errors.
Mar 30 11:56:36 raspberrypi ovpn-server[27334]: Use --help for more information.
=============================================
::::            Debug complete           ::::
:::
::: Debug output completed above.
::: Copy saved to /tmp/debug.log
:::
```

Focusing on the error:
`--writepid fails with '/run/openvpn/server.pid': No such file or directory (errno=2)`

I couldn't find any working solutions for this and trying to manually start the server doesn't seem to do anything:

`sudo OpenVPN /etc/openvpn/server/server.conf`

> 2022-03-30 12:15:25 Consider setting groups/curves preference with tls-groups instead of forcing a specific curve with ecdh-curve.

> pi@raspberrypi:/etc/openvpn/server $

Looking at the status of the OpenVPN service makes it seem like it is running okay:

`systemctl service openvpn`

```
● openvpn.service - OpenVPN service
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/openvpn.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (exited) since Wed 2022-03-30 11:56:42 BST; 27min ago
    Process: 27361 ExecStart=/bin/true (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
   Main PID: 27361 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
        CPU: 16ms

Mar 30 11:56:42 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Starting OpenVPN service...
Mar 30 11:56:42 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Finished OpenVPN service.
```

Any suggestions or help would be greatly appreciated, I am quite new to networking and this is the first problem I have had to give in to and ask the experts. If I have missed any information or useful outputs that could help with suggestions let me know.

Comment: This was solved by the following on related question https://serverfault.com/questions/1003011/openvpn-error-cannot-open-tun-tap-dev-dev-net-tun-no-such-file-or-directory : `mkdir -p /dev/net
mknod /dev/net/tun c 10 200
chmod 600 /dev/net/tun

/etc/init.d/openvpn restart`

Answer (score 0):

[OpenVPN - ERROR: Cannot open TUN/TAP dev /dev/net/tun: No such file or directory (errno=2)](https://serverfault.com/questions/1003011/openvpn-error-cannot-open-tun-tap-dev-dev-net-tun-no-such-file-or-directory)

```
#!/bin/bash

mkdir -p /dev/net
mknod /dev/net/tun c 10 200
chmod 600 /dev/net/tun

/etc/init.d/openvpn restart
```

Comment: Please add why you want to the things you do to clarify how to fix the problem.